# How to filter strings from one stream which are not contained in another sream?

Tags: java, java-stream

I have two streams of Strings like :

```
Stream<String> thisWeekFile = Files.lines(thisWeekPath);
Stream<String> lastWeekFile = Files.lines(lastWeekPath);
```

In comparison to last week this weeks file can have the same strings, some strings added or some strings removed. For now I'm only interested in the strings which were present in last weeks file but not any more in this weeks file. How do i get those strings? I tried

```
lastWeekFile.filter(e->!thisWeekFile.anyMatch(e));
```

The above giving an error :String can not be converted to predicate.

Idealy i want something like

```
lastWeekFile.filter(e->!thisWeekFile.contains(e));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `Files.readLines()` method that returns List instead of stream it can be done without stream api:

```
List<String> thisWeekFile = Files.readAllLines(thisWeekPath);
List<String> lastWeekFile = Files.readAllLines(lastWeekPath);

lastWeekFile.removeAll(thisWeekFile);
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to `collect` the streams and then possibly remove(updated existin) entries for `lastWeekFile` :

```
Set<String> thisWeekFile = Files.lines(thisWeekPath).collect(Collectors.toSet());
List<String> lastWeekFile = Files.lines(lastWeekPath)).collect(Collectors.toList());
lastWeekFile.removeIf(e -> !thisWeekFile.contains(e));
```

Comment: Of course, you can collect the filtered values in a new collection as well.

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
lastWeekFile.filter(e->Files.lines(thisWeekPath).noneMatch(o -> o.equals(e)))...;
```

Note that you cannot consume the same stream more than once, so you'll have to generate this week's `Stream` multiple times.

Comment: This is sort of O(n^2)

Comment: @user7 well, the OP asked how to do the task with Streams, so that's what I answered. Of course it can be done more efficiently by transforming the Streams to Collections.

Comment: Yes. No problems with that. I just *commented* about the complexity. It has nothing to do with the correctness of your solution :)